# How to write Django views (JSON apis) with statically typed arguments and responses?

Tags: python, django, types

In Java Spring, I can write down (simplified):

```
List<Apple> fetchApples(Orange request) { ... }

class Orange { int a; double b; String c; ... }
class Apple { int d; double e; String f; ... }
```

By doing this, I can be very sure that users of the API will only pass in some data like `{a: 42, b: 1.2, c: "hello"}`, instead of `{a: "wtf", z: [1,2,3]}`. However, in Django, I do not find any method to hint this. I have to use `a = int(request['a'])` to manually convert that parameter into type `int` and so on. This is even more troublesome when dealing with more complicated structs.

Thus, how can I do something similar to Java Spring? I know Django/Python is not statically typed, but a type hint is better than nothing.

Why I need this: Firstly, more typing is better for the code (more errors can be found at lint time). Secondly, and most importantly, I want to **run code generator** but that definitely requires some static typing hinting. For example, generate Dart/Flutter client of the Django server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who see this question, here are my two cents.

Finally, I use FastAPI instead, since I am doing JSON requests and responses. Notice Django ORM works well even if we are using FastAPI for handling requests/responses.